# Intellij code style setting to wrap multiline function arguments

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In my current (almost default) configuration, this method is formatted this way:

```
public MyBean myMethod(String param1, String param2, String param3,
                       String param4) {
   ...
}
```

But I would like to be formatted with this other style:

```
public MyBean myMethod(String param1, String param2, String param3,
    String param4) {
   ...
}
```

I've playing with the Java "Wrapping and Braces" options, but with no luck :(

Answer (score 2):

This setting can be found in the settings dialog, under Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces -> Method declaration parameters -> align when multiline. You should uncheck the checkmark.

[image]

Comment: Great! I don't know why didn't work last time when I tried this same option. May be the integration with EditorConfig was handling this behabior and not the IntelliJ configuration :(